# {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027PersonID\u0027."

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm trying to make ajax call to pull up data in jqgrid via asmx webservice but I'm getting this Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter error.

The function works well if I remove the input parameter in the web service call and ajax request but the issue persists once I have the input paramter.

Following is the web service method

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public PersonsGrid Per(string PersonID)
    {
        ....
        return personsGrid;
    }
```

Following is the Ajax call:

```
function getGridInfo() {

    var personId = document.getElementById('txtPersonID').value;           

    $("#PersonsInfo").jqGrid({

        url: '/Service/PersonsService.asmx/GetPersonsInfo',
        data: "{'PersonID': '" + personId + "'}",

        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        async: false,
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records" },
        loadonce: false,
        colNames: ['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Phone'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 100 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: 'Persons info',
        loadError: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var error_msg = xhr.responseText;
            var msg = "Some error occured during processing:";
            msg += '\n\n' + error_msg;
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

Any idea on how to overcome this issue. I followed several other posts but that still did not work. It has to do something with the data parameter in the ajax request.

Comment: Shouldn't your mType be 'GET' rather than 'POST'?

Comment: Even though with that, I will get the same error, I also added usehttpget = true in the web method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option

```
 data: "{'PersonID': '" + personId + "'}"
```

contains two error:

1. jqGrid don't "know" `data` parameter, which exist in jQuery.ajax. Instead of that one can use `postData` parameter.
2. The string like `{'PersonID': 'same_value'}` is wrong JSON string, because JSON require to use `"` instead of `'`. You can fix the code by usage
3. If you use `data` or `postData` as JSON string then you should remove `serializeGridData`.

```js
postData: '{"PersonID": "' + personId + '"}'
```

but such code will still contains bad code. I'd recommend you to use `JSON.stringify` instead, which convert an object to JSON string:

```
postData: JSON.stringify({PersonID: personId})
```

Alternatively you can remove `data` and `postData` and use the following `serializeGridData`:

```
serializeGridData: function () {
    return JSON.stringify({PersonID: personId});
}
```

Such callback function ignores the standard parameter, which send jqGrid and it will send `PersonID` parameter in JSON format instead.

Comment: This worked, I used the alternative option
    serializeGridData: function () {
    return JSON.stringify({PersonID: personId});
    }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
data: "{'PersonID': '" + personId + "'}",
```

to

```
postData: "{'PersonID': '" + personId + "'}",
```

as you appear to be referencing postData in the serializeGridData function.

Comment: I also tried that but still it is giving the same error message

Answer (score 0):

By definition postData parameter is a object and it can't be a string. More of the type of parameters [can be read here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options)

So, IMHO the clear solution is to set a postData as object and use serializeGridData like this:

```
...jqGrid({
    ...
    postData : { "PersonID" : personId },
    serializeGridData : function( postData ) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    ...
 });
```

Kind Regards

Comment: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) allows to use `string` as the value of `data` parameter and not only `PlainObject` used typically. The function `$.extend()` can be called with `string` at the first parameter and the string will be not changed. Thus `postData: "some string"` can be used as the short form to call `$.ajax` with `data: "some string"`. If you use `type: "POST"` then the string "some string" will be just placed in the body of the Ajax request. Thus `postData: "some string"` works too. One need just construct the string value of `postData` like the server expect.

Comment: Sure it is so, but constructing a string with parameters is very difficult, especially if there is a need to add more variables - you will need to add a lot of ` + ' and " ` . The clear and code readable way is to construct first the object and then use JSON.stringify - but at end this is a matter of choice.